# What do you call the activity where people mingle at a social event?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

My monolingual dictionaries tell me that the word "mingle" can only be used as a verb in English, something that is confirmed by various google searches. So, what could I use instead, to say "The party will begin with a mingle, and then there is a sit-down meal" in a more idiomatic way? Is there another noun for this activity, or do I have to rephrase completely? My bilingual dictionary is not of much help, since that suggests "mingle", used as a noun...

Comment: You can use it as a noun if you like and it'll be understood. If you're hesitant, just say it'll start with "some time to mingle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Mingle" really means to put yourself into a crowd. At a social event, 'mingling' suggests branching out and meeting new people rather than those you are already familiar with. We don't formally use "mingle" as a noun in the way you suggest, although an individual might informally say "I'm going for a mingle", perhaps? I don't believe there is a noun in popular use for a designated time like that.

I think you just need the word "socialise", or "socialising". The most common ways of saying this would probably be:

> The party began with some **socialising**, followed by a sit-down meal.

or

> The party began with some **time to socialise**, followed by a sit-down meal.

Perhaps at more formal parties, there might be "introductions" - where people are formally introduced to one another, and that word might be used to describe that time. Most people - although this much is perhaps opinion - find 'forced' introductions at social gatherings to be awkward, and prefer mingling to be a personal choice and introductions to happen naturally.

Answer (score 1):

It's unnatural to put "mingling" as an event on a schedule, but you can put *time for mingling* on a schedule.

> The party will begin with **time for mingling**, followed by a sit-down meal.

"A mingle" sounds like a whole social event in itself, like a gathering designed for people to meet new people and get to know each other, rather than part of a party.